# How do you send an email with an attachment using cfscript in CF9?

Tags: email, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfmail

How do you do the following using cfscript?

```
<cfmail
   from="me@domain.com"
   to="you@domain.com"
   subject="Attachments">
   <cfmailparam name="Reply-To" value="me@domain.com">
   Some message goes here...
   <cfmailparam file="c:\files\readme.txt">
   <cfmailparam file="c:\files\logo.gif">
</cfmail>
```

Using the following causes a "function keyword is missing in FUNCTION declaration" error:

```
mail subject="Test Email" from="me@domain.com to="you@domain.com" server="localhost" {
    mailpart file="#ExpandPath('readme.txt')#";
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a how-to explaining what needs to be done: http://simonbingham.posterous.com/sending-email-using-cfscript-in-coldfusion-9

```
// Create an instance of the mail object
mail=new mail();

// Set it's properties
mail.setSubject( "Sample Email" );
mail.setTo( "to@example.com" );
mail.setFrom( "from@example.com" );
mail.setCC( "cc@example.com" );
mail.setBCC( "bcc@example.com" );

// Add an attachment
mail.addParam( file="C:\foo.txt" );

// Add email body content in text and HTML formats
mail.addPart( type="text", charset="utf-8", wraptext="72", body="This is a test message." );
mail.addPart( type="html", charset="utf-8", body="<p>This is a test message.</p>" );

// Send the email
mail.send();
```